# Directly increasing an int in a List of objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, object, int

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>();

objects.Add(5);
```

I want to do

```
objects[0] += 10;
```

But I need to cast it first.

```
int a = (int) objects[0];
a += 10;
```

But doing this only changes a, not the integer in the list.

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
objects[0] = ((int)objects[0]) + 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly increase the boxed integer that is stored in the list, because boxed structs are immutable.  Jack Edmonds' solution is about as close as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

have a list of integers instead ;p

```
List<int> objects = new List<int>();
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for :D